# Getting error while parsing json in NSJSON serialization in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift2, swift3, nsjsonserialization

```
 func connectionDidFinishLoading(_ connection: NSURLConnection)
    {

    NSLog("\(statusResponseData)")

    let strData:NSDictionary! = (try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: statusResponseData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary
```

I am getting the following error when I converted my code from swift 2.2 to swift 3.0.

> Cannot invoke json object with an argument of list type(with NSMutable data! options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions).

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: Read the Swift 3 release notes, which you didn't do, and read what changes you have to make to Swift 2 code. Don't use mutableContainers unless you know why. And I hope you're aware that your code will crash if there is any problem.

Comment: @gnasher729. I am new to swift.Can you please help me with my code?

Answer (score 0):

replace :

```
 let strData:NSDictionary! = (try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: statusResponseData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary
```

with:

```
 if let strData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: statusResponseData, options: []) as! JSONObject {
        //Do what you need to!
      }
```

I have no idea why all tutorials suggests the `mutableContainers` option. You don't need it at all in Swift when using native collection types.

Comment: Why? It's called "cargo cult programming".